# Two WebApis in one solution

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have two webApis project in my solution, they are separted, but i want to debug them using one swagger, how to implent it in .Net Core 7, so i want o debug it more eficient and in proper way

I tried AddMVC and others, but no result

Comment: .AddApplicationPart()

Comment: Using swagger for both project is not supported because each project has its own swagger configuration integrated by design.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Because you can run a single project in debug mode, if the project references contain another project, you can access the contents of that project while in debug mode. However, this method is a very erroneous approach. In addition, it is not possible to reach the endpoints of the 2nd Api project with this method.

If it's a really necessary change, you can add Fields to your project and put the endpoints of the 2nd API project in this field. Actions added to the fields will be accessed with their specific url addresses.

If you want to know more about areas, you can check the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0)